# How to deal with a 301 (redirect)?

Tags: reactjs, api, http, redirect

Very new to react so bear with me. I have got a webapi that on its GET it returns a redirect response, I believe the http code is 301.

How do I in React make my browser redirect to the webpage that coming from my api using fetch after a buttonclick?

I thought it would be as simple as just getting a fetch and not doing anything with it, but clearly nothing is happening

```
handleSubmit(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    fetch("https://localhost:44323/Redirection")
}
```

Comment: Not sure what your goal is, but is this redirect URL completely different from the react app? I mean is it going to redirect to the same app or totally different website?

Comment: @SanishJoseph totally different website. I am basically trying to create a url-shortener. And the backend sends back a http301 request to the a url (e.g google.com)

Comment: What is expected from your react app? Show the short URL as a link and when user clicks it, go to that link?

Comment: @SanishJoseph it is supposed to directly redirect the browser to that link

Comment: Try window.location.replace('https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location.reload');